# How to parse 8-digit date in C++?

Tags: c++, date, parsing

I use `std::get_time` to parse dates from text. In most cases it is sufficient, but when reading dates with no separators (e.g. `31122021`, with format `"%d%m%Y"`) I always get a failure. I use this because I saw it described as an equivalent to python's `strptime` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33542189/15061775) which *does* manage this use case ([How to parse an 8 digit number as a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66889704)).

Here is my code (tested MRE) :

```
#include <cassert>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>

#define MAKEDATE(d,m,y) (((y&0xFFFF)<<16)|((m&0xFF)<<8)|(d&0xFF))
uint32_t Get_Date(const char *str_date, const char **out, const char *format)
{
    std::tm dt = {};
    std::istringstream stream(str_date);
    stream >> std::get_time(&dt, format);
    if (stream.fail())
    {
        if (out) *out = NULL;
        return MAKEDATE(1, 1, 1900);
    }
    else
    {
        if (out) *out = str_date + (int)stream.tellg();
        return MAKEDATE(dt.tm_mday, 1 + dt.tm_mon, 1900 + dt.tm_year);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    assert(Get_Date("31122021", NULL, "%d%m%Y") == MAKEDATE(31, 12, 2021));
}
```

I compile it using VS2017's default compiler settings using MFC and CLI, with MSVC 19.10.25027.

Did I make a mistake? Is there another flag or set of flags I could use? Is there another, simple parsing method?

Comment: "31122021"- that's January 31st, 22021? That's a good 200 centuries out. You may want a less ambiguous date format.

Comment: @MSalters That's a standard format though. `%Y` is supposed to parse the year as a 4-digit number (with leading zeroes permitted but not required). Also, this exact example is handled correctly when compiling with CLang.

Comment: Fixed in 16.9 (VS2019): https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/944

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a compiler specific issue. If this specific method needs to handle this specific input, then you have to use a different compiler.

Quoting this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e500e3a8-fd83-48af-adde-a438a61de102) ;

> It appears that std::get_time in MSVC 14.0 does not parse undelimited date and time values, such as those found in the ISO-8601 basic format.  The following code fails with MSVC, but works properly with GCC 5.2. <code example>

and

> Seems that it is known: <defunct, very old link>

one can conclude MSVC-compiled `std::get_time` has never been able to parse non-separated input. GCC reportedly works, and CLang definitely does, so MSVC is the odd one out.

If switching compilers is not worth the hassle, a more specific parsing method will do.

```
// Assuming str_date is guaranteed to be 8 digits
uint32_t Get_Date_YMD(const char *str_date)
{
    return
        (((str_date[0] - '0') * 1000 +
        (  str_date[1] - '0') * 100 +
        (  str_date[2] - '0') * 10 +
        (  str_date[3] - '0')) << 16) |
        (((str_date[4] - '0') * 10 +
        (  str_date[5] - '0')) << 8) |
        (( str_date[6] - '0') * 10 +
        (  str_date[7] - '0'));
}
```